# Azure VM OS Disk up gradation from HDD to SSD

Tags: azure

I want to upgrade my Classic Azure VM OS disk only(c drive) to SSD. It is old classic VM.Can someone help me. It is our production server. Hence, suggest with 
 most suitable way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way to upgrade a classic VM disk to Premium (SSD). The only way is to create a new Premium Storage Account and copy the .VHD file over that corresponds to your VM C: Drive and then spin up a new VM using that file as the boot disk.

My recommendation is to migrate the VM to ARM and then converting the disk to a managed premium disk

[Migrate a Classic VM to an ARM Managed Disk VM | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migrate-single-classic-to-resource-manager)

It's actually possible to perform the migration without downtime, but first you have to migrate the VM from Classic to ARM and then you migrate the Storage.

[Migrate to Resource Manager with PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)